# Process terminating when breakpoint reached

Tags: ollydbg, anti-debugging, x64dbg, breakpoint

I want to set breakpoint on the `recv` function to replace the received packets. But, I can not put breakpoint on any instruction in the program, the process simply closes with code 4000001f. I also tried a hardware breakpoint, but that doesn't help.
I have installed TitanHide plugins etc. but also without result.

I use x32dbg (32 bit target program). And recently read [this article](http://waleedassar.blogspot.com/2013/01/wow64-specific-anti-debug-trick.html).
But x64 debugger does not allow to open x32 application. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you share the executable? If not, you may find helpful [this work](https://anti-reversing.com/Downloads/Anti-Reversing/The_Ultimate_Anti-Reversing_Reference.pdf).

Comment: @bart1e Thanks a lot for this book. Can you link your email? I will send the application